# Listview puts the same images in every group

Tags: c#, listview

My listview should make a group for every directory on a specified path, and add the pictures from each directory to the group that was created for it; but instead it adds the pictures from the last directory to each group.
Any ideas how can i solve this problem?
Thank you!

```
       private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    

      string path = @"C:\pics\";
      string[] tabs_needed = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path);


        foreach (string folder in tabs_needed)
        {
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(folder);
            listBox1.Items.Add(f.Name);
            TabPage ghhk = new TabPage(f.Name);
            tabControl1.Controls.Add(ghhk);
            ListView listView1 = new ListView();
            ghhk.Controls.Add(listView1);
            listView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            string new_path = path + f.Name;

    string[] groups_needed =System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(new_path);



            foreach (string ufolder in groups_needed)
            {

                FileInfo uf = new FileInfo(ufolder);

         string f_path = String.Concat(new_path + @"\" + uf.Name + @"\");
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(f_path);
                ImageList imagelist = new ImageList();

                foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
                {

                    try
                    {
                       imagelist.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));

                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }

                }

                imagelist.ImageSize = new Size(32, 32);

                listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;

                ListViewGroup gr1 = new ListViewGroup(uf.Name);
                listView1.Groups.Add(gr1);
                string tpath = String.Concat(f_path, "gf.txt");

                for (int counter = 0; counter < imagelist.Images.Count; counter++)
                {

                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                    item.Text = File.ReadAllLines(tpath).Skip(counter).Take(1).First();
                    item.ImageIndex = counter;


                    item.Group = gr1;
                    listView1.Items.Add(item);

                }
                 listView1.LargeImageList = imagelist;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are instantiating the ImageList each time in the foreach loop. When you assign the imagelist finally to listView1.LargeImageList, it is only the final imagelist instance that gets attached.

You will need to move the instantiation out of the foreach loop

```
ImageList imagelist = new ImageList();

foreach (string ufolder in groups_needed)
{
    ...
}
```

You may also need to change the logic for your ImageIndex to get this working, now that the ImageList is out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
listView1.LargeImageList = imagelist;
```

with

```
listView1.LargeImageList.Images.AddRange(imagelist.Images.Cast<System.Drawing.Image>().ToArray())
```

Because you are overwriting image list at each cycle.

Comment: it gives an error: Error 1 "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ImageList.ImageCollection.AddRange(System.Drawing.Image[])' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: now it says : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: check if imagelist.Images is!=null before you cast it. And check if LargeImageList or LargeImageList.Images are null. If so when you instantiate listView1 just take care to instantiate them as well.